# RadioButton functionality in custom component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I am trying to create an xmxl component which contains an image and a radio button.
The main application script will use several of these components.

I am having problems trying to get the RadioGroup to function properly.
I have binded a variable on the RadioButton groupName attribute in the component mxml file so I can set this in the main application script.

This functions properly as when I tab through each RadioGroup, only the first radiobutton of each group gets the focus.
But when I click each radio button in a group, the previous one does not deselect.

I have read that I cannot bind component id's so how else can I achieve selecting only one radio button in each group?
Do I need to implement IFocusManager?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Each group of RadioButtons needs a RadioButtonGroup assigned to the groupName. The RadioButtonGroup makes sure only 1 button is selected at a time.
The RadioButtonGroup is declared in `<fx:Declarations>` and is the name of the RadioButtonGroup is assigned in the groupName property.

```
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="paymentType" itemClick="handlePayment(event);"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:VGroup paddingLeft="10" paddingTop="10">
        <s:RadioButton groupName="paymentType" 
                       id="payCheck" 
                       value="check" 
                       label="Pay by check" 
                       width="150"/>
        <s:RadioButton groupName="paymentType" 
                       id="payCredit" 
                       value="credit" 
                       label="Pay by credit card" 
                       width="150"/>
    </s:VGroup>
```

The Apache Flex reference: http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/RadioButtonGroup.html

Comment: Thank you. From further reading, I understand that I have to implement the IFocusManagerGroup Interface and then implement the get and set functions for selected and groupName. I have managed to implement groupName but I am having problems with selected. What component is resposible for calling the selected method on all radiobuttons within the same group name? I need to know this so I can mirror this functionality in my own custom component.

Comment: If you are rolling your own implementation of a RadioGroup, then you should extend your classes to include RadioButton and RadioButtonGroup so you get the their functionality.

Comment: Please see the following question which provides some code and hopefully explains what I am trying to do -----
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130522/using-radiobuttongroup-funcitonality-across-multiple-custom-components ---- I have tried to change the skinnablecontainer to mx:UIComponent but then I get an error -> 'Label' declaration must be contained within the <Declarations> tag since it does not implement 'mx.core.IUIComponent'. Any ideas?